# Onchange jQuery Event for Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown with 3 selectors. I wanted to show the content of each of the selector onchange. Can someone help?

Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/M5JCiCq2qo

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("filter-extras").value;
  document.getElementById("extra-filter").innerHTML = "You selected: " +
    x;
}
```

```html
<label class="col-md-12 pl-0">Select Type</label>
<select class="form-control custom-select mb-3 col-md-4" onchange="myFunction()" id="filter-extras">
  <option selected="selected" value="fuel">Fuel replacement</option>
  <option value="wifi">Portable WiFi hotspot</option>
  <option value="cleaning">Post-trip cleaning</option>
</select>

<div>Content for Fuel replacement</div>
<div>Content for Portable WiFi hotspot</div>
<div>Content for Post-trip cleaning</div>
```

I think with jQuery it would be easier to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make two versions with identical behavior and default content displayed.
Here we simply check in `forEach` loop if id is equal to selected value:

```js
document.getElementById('filter-extras').addEventListener('change', myFunction)

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('filter-extras').value;
  document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.getAttribute('id') === x) {
      element.style = 'display:block'
    } else {
      element.style = 'display:none'
    }
  });
}

myFunction()
```

```html
<label class="col-md-12 pl-0">Select Type</label>
<select class="form-control custom-select mb-3 col-md-4" id="filter-extras">
  <option selected="selected" value="fuel">Fuel replacement</option>
  <option value="wifi">Portable WiFi hotspot</option>
  <option value="cleaning">Post-trip cleaning</option>
</select>

<div class="content" id="fuel">Content for Fuel replacement</div>
<div class="content" id="wifi">Content for Portable WiFi hotspot</div>
<div class="content" id="cleaning">Content for Post-trip cleaning</div>
```

```js
$("#filter-extras").on("change", myFunction)

function myFunction() {
  var x = $("#filter-extras").val();
  $('.content').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') === x) {
      $(this).show()
    } else {
      $(this).hide()
    }
  })
}

myFunction()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-md-12 pl-0">Select Type</label>
<select class="form-control custom-select mb-3 col-md-4" id="filter-extras">
  <option selected="selected" value="fuel">Fuel replacement</option>
  <option value="wifi">Portable WiFi hotspot</option>
  <option value="cleaning">Post-trip cleaning</option>
</select>

<div id="fuel" class="content">Content for Fuel replacement</div>
<div id="wifi" class="content">Content for Portable WiFi hotspot</div>
<div id="cleaning" class="content">Content for Post-trip cleaning</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This can still be done quite easily with plain JS. You just need to add the `change` event handler to the `select`, then you can use the `value` chosen to select the content to show and hide all the others, something like this:

```js
var content = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

document.querySelector('#filter-extras').addEventListener('change', function() {
  content.forEach(function(el) { el.style.display = 'none'; });
  document.querySelector('#' + this.value).style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
.content { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="col-md-12 pl-0">Select Type</label>
<select class="form-control custom-select mb-3 col-md-4" id="filter-extras">
  <option selected="selected" value="fuel">Fuel replacement</option>
  <option value="wifi">Portable WiFi hotspot</option>
  <option value="cleaning">Post-trip cleaning</option>
</select>

<div class="content" id="fuel">Content for Fuel replacement</div>
<div class="content" id="wifi">Content for Portable WiFi hotspot</div>
<div class="content" id="cleaning">Content for Post-trip cleaning</div>
```

If you did want to do it in jQuery, here is the same logic translated:

```js
var $content = $('.content');

$('#filter-extras').on('change', function() {
  $content.hide();
  $('#' + this.value).show();
});
```

```css
.content { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-md-12 pl-0">Select Type</label>
<select class="form-control custom-select mb-3 col-md-4" id="filter-extras">
  <option selected="selected" value="fuel">Fuel replacement</option>
  <option value="wifi">Portable WiFi hotspot</option>
  <option value="cleaning">Post-trip cleaning</option>
</select>

<div class="content" id="fuel">Content for Fuel replacement</div>
<div class="content" id="wifi">Content for Portable WiFi hotspot</div>
<div class="content" id="cleaning">Content for Post-trip cleaning</div>
```

Comment: The default content is not loading which is of "Fuel replacement" dropdown. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I think you already got your answer but if you want to show selected content by default on load then you should add this line to you code

// so in order to show the content of "Fuel replacement" as it is selected

```
$( function({
    const contentToShow = $('#filter-extras').val();
    $('#' + contentToShow).show();

   // after this you can add the code here
      $('#filter-extras').change(()=>{
        // show hide content here
      });
});
```